# How to develop this Eclipse plug-in: add a menu in the page "properties for XXXProject"

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm going on developing an Eclipse plugin: collect a config for a project. I want to write a GUI for every project properties so that user can input every config item.

How can I implement it. I have researched for some days, just find a way to add a menu in Eclipse Preferences.

But I want to add menu to project properties. Like: User right-click the project in Eclipse, then click Properties, config menu is in left of the properties dialog.

What should I do?

Comment: You can add entries to the tree on the left of the properties dialog, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, can you give me some tips about how to add entries to the tree on the left of the properties dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add to the properties tree by using the [org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_propertyPages.html) extension point in your plugin.

An example property page declaration:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
   <page
        class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.ResourceInfoPage"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.propertypages.info.file"
        name="Resource"
        >
     <enabledWhen>
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>
     </enabledWhen>
   </page>
```

The above is the declaration of the `Resource` property page taken from Eclipse. It declares that the property page is provided by the `ResourceInfoPage` class and that it is only shown (enabled) when the selected object is an `IResource` (a project, folder or file).

The property page class that you write should extend the `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyPage` class. so a skeleton class would be:

```java
public class MyPropertyPage extends PropertyPage
{
  @Override
  protected Control createContents(Composite parent)
  {
    IAdaptable selectedObject = getElement();

    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    // TODO add your controls here

    return composite;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean performDefaults()
  {
    // TODO deal with Defaults button
  }

  @Override
  public boolean performOk()
  {
    // TODO deal with OK button
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, greg.  But I'm a newer for Eclipse plugin developing, I did as you said, but there is no entry on the tree in property dialog.              There is my practice: 1. Create a plug-in project.     2. Open plugin.xml in manifest editor. Navigate to extension page. Add an extension "org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages" using default name and class.           I found the plugin.xml and the propertyPage code structure are same as you said. But when I run as eclipse application, there is still no customized entry in tree.      Was I missed something?

Comment: You probably have the wrong `enabledWhen` value. What object is selected when to try to show the properties?

Comment: I selected IResource. There is my plugin.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
      <page name="Sample Page"
            nameFilter="*.*"
            class="com.myplugin.rmp.properties.SamplePropertyPage"
            id="com.myplugin.rmp.properties.samplePropertyPage">
         <enabledWhen>
            <instanceof
                  value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            </instanceof>  
         </enabledWhen>
      </page>
   </extension>

</plugin>

Comment: I have found what happens. The config nameFilter="." is wrong. Delete it or modify it to "*" will works.   Thanks, greg.